# Loop nested nodes in Symfony Crawler

Tags: php, symfony, dom

How to loop through all nodes of Dom.

I use latest Symfony Crawler.

Simple example:

```
<?php

function test()
{
    $crawler = new Crawler($html);

    $crawler
        ->filter('body > ul')
        ->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
            loop($node);
        });
}

function loop(Crawler $node)
{
    static $counter;

    if ($node->filter('ul')->count() > 0) {
        loop($node);
    }

    $counter++;
    echo PHP_EOL,'Node: ', $counter, PHP_EOL;
}
```

I get a message:

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached,
>   aborting! in
>   /.../vendor/symfony/css-selector/XPath/Extension/NodeExtension.php on line 269

HTML for example:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>foo</li>
                <li>bar</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>baz</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>buz</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>uaz</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a stack overflow on your recursive call before you get any trace data.  Try putting an if($counter <90) around the call to loop() to quit before a stack overflow.

Comment: Yep, it loops for example when I put `if($counter < 10)`, if I put `if($counter < 90)` fails again.

Comment: Does your trace now show the route it is walking the tree?  You should be able to work out why it' snot walking the tree the way you expect.

Comment: So you run `loop` with the same node? Isn't it an infinite recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the value of `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250` in your php.ini: 
http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level

Comment: Why I should increase nesting level for nesting of 4 nodes?

Comment: This is a xdebug error, on a production server you will not get it, so in order to get rid of it 1. Make the nesting lvl bigger or 2. Remove xdebug